# increase count with drag gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

Can you please tell me if it is possible to increase/decrease the counter when using DragGesture, here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var count: Int = 0
@State private var offset: CGSize = .zero

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 15) {
        Text("\(count)")
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .frame(width: 250, height: 350)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10)
            .offset(x: offset.width)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            offset = value.translation
                            if offset.width > 150 {
                                count += 1
                            } else if offset.width < -150 {
                                count -= 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            offset = .zero
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the counter constantly increases/decreases after overcoming the coordinates set in the conditions on the x-axis, and the idea is that it increases/decreases by one and the figure returned to its initial location, adding the following code also did not help:

```
 .onChanged { value in
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        offset = value.translation
                        if offset.width > 150 {
                            count += 1
                            offset = .zero
                        } else if offset.width < -150 {
                            count -= 1
                            offset = .zero
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Please tell me how to perform this task.

Comment: This is more math issue rather than code issue!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is how you are changing your count. What you want to do is take the remainder of the offset amount divided by the amount you want the drag to have moved before you increment. To give an example, think of a ruler. You put your finger on 1 and drag up. Until you get to 2, you don't want anything to change. Once you get to 2, and keep dragging, you don't want anything to change until you hit 3. That is what the remainder gives you is the number of times you have dragged 150 points. If you want it to change sooner, decrease the points from 150, less often, increase it.

Edit below to correct my math error. (I should not try coding on my phone):

You want to divide the offset.height by 150 (or whatever amount of movement you want to trigger the change) and use the integer quotient as your count. So, you would change your code like this:

```
.onChanged { value in
    withAnimation(.spring()) {
        offset = value.translation
        // You want the quotient of the offset / 150
        // Then take the additive inverse for iOS coordinates. (remove the - for macOS)
        count = -Int(offset.height / 150)
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: It has same issue as before!